# plotly Line chart from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a dataframe and wanted to create a line chart on one of the columns using plotly.

I have the following code but its not working

```
df['col1'].iplot(kind='scatter', filename='cufflinks/cf-simple-line')
```

Can anyone see why? I'm not sure if I should use .offline or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `cf.go_offline()` code run as expected:

```
import plotly.offline as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
import cufflinks as cf

cf.go_offline()

df0 = pd.DataFrame({"fruits": ["apple", "mango", "lime"],
                    "number of sold items": [20, 26, 32]})

df0["fruits"].iplot(kind="scatter", filename="lineplot-with-cufflinks")
```

Output:
[image: Simple plot]